# Deleting remote branches on git with dash in name

Tags: git

I can't delete a remote branch that has a dash in the name.

```
git push origin :paul-ms
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: paul-ms
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:blah/blah.git'

git push origin --delete 'paul-ms'
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: paul-ms
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:blah/blah.git'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use: `git push origin :refs/heads/paul-ms`

See: [Git - The Refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)